# Is there a closed form representation of this logical function?

Tags: functions

Is there a closed form representation of the function $f(x,y)$, for $x,y \in \mathbb{C}$, such that $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }x=y \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

The first constraint is easily realized by $e^{x-y}$. I can't seem to think of an expression of $x$ and $y$ that is identically $0$ if $x$ is *not* equal to $y$.

Comment: Do you consider a piecewise definition not be a closed form?

Comment: What is wrong with the function definition: $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}1 & x=y \\ 0 & x \neq y\end{cases}$$

Comment: This function is not continuous, so when you write it in "closed form" it cannot be made of elementary functions which are continuous. What sort of answer would you expect?

Comment: I guess the closest you can get to a closed form is $f(x,y)=\chi_L(x,y)$ where $L$ is the 'line' $x=y$.

Comment: There are other notations similar to what @GitGud suggested, such as the Iverson bracket $[x=y]$ and the Kronecker delta $\delta_{xy}$. Admittedly, these are oftenest use with integral arguments, but nothing prevents them from being used in this way.

Comment: @Shaktal That's the function of which I requested an alternate representation. Nothing's wrong with it, but had I not wanted an alternative, I wouldn't have come here to ask, now, would I?

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{C}$ forms a field, so it has no non-zero zero divisors. Furthermore, the term "closed form" is (with a singular exception), without a standardized definition. Your usage aligns with a common usage, which means "expressible by elementary functions." However, all of the elementary functions are continuous, and your desired result is not. Combining this with the lack of zero divisors, and you will not get something in nice closed form.

Now, supposed we admitted $|\cdot|$ and $\operatorname{sgn}(\cdot)$ into the class of elementary functions. Then we could write $$f(x,y) = 1-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-y)|.$$

Here, we define the $\operatorname{sgn}(\cdot)$ function for complex numbers as $$\operatorname{sgn}(z) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} \frac{z}{|z|}, & z \neq 0, \\ 0, & z = 0, \end{array}\right.$$
in keeping with a convention found in some computational environments.

Comment: I thought that the notion of "sign" existed only in ordered field, which $\Bbb C$ is blatantly not.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Good catch! I totally overlooked that, but an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution for what you want:
$$
f(x) = 0^{|x-y|}
$$
noting that $0^z = 0$ when $z > 0$ and, by definition, $0^0 = 1$.

I still think it's better to write out the piecewise definition, which is clearer.

Comment: $0^{-1}$ is $\infty$, not $0$.  Your expression only evaluates to $0$ if the real part of $x-y$ is positive.

Comment: @Arkamis In this case, $z = |x-y| \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Just saw that. Tiny little absolute value bars! Or aging eyes... :(

Answer (score 0):

How about $f(x,y)= \chi_x(x)\chi_x(y) $?

Just noticed this is a variant of GitGud's answer, which I just read.