# Closed-form expressions for periodic sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, periodic-functions

Given a periodic sequence (with period $p$) of real numbers $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, with each $a_n$ expressible *individually* in closed-form. Is it always possible to give a *single* closed-form expression, in terms of $n$, that expresses *all* the $a_n$'s?

Comment: Yes. Using the $p$th roots of unity $\omega_1$, $\omega_2$, ..., $\omega_p$, there exists some coefficients $b_1$, $b_2$, ..., $b_p$, such that, for every $n$, $$a_n=\sum_{m=1}^pb_m(\omega_m)^n.$$ This translates into a formula with real coefficients $u_m$ and $v_m$ as $$a_n=\sum_{m=1}^pu_m\cos(2\pi mn/p)+v_m\sin(2\pi mn/p).$$

Comment: @Did: Not sure I follow, also, is it possible to do it w/out using $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Is $a_n = a_{n \mod p}$ not what you're looking for?

Comment: @benguin: If $p>1$, how is that still a single formula for every $a_n$? I should specify that the close-form expression is for the function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{ a_n|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ such that $n\mapsto a_n$

Comment: I assumed that you have the closed form representation of $a_n$ in terms of $n$ for $n \in \{0, 1, \dots, p-1\}$.  Is this not the case?

Comment: For example, if I know $a_n = \sin(n)$ for $n \in \{0, 1, \dots, p-1\}$ and if $a_n$ is $p$ periodic, then I know for general $n$, we have $a_n = \sin(n \mod p)$.

Comment: @benguin: We have closed-form representations for *each* $a_n$ *individually*. The point is to construct a single closed form expression that gives *all* the $a_n$'s.

Comment: If we define $f_{n,p}(x) = 1$ if $x \equiv n \mod p$ and $f_{n,p}(x) = 0$ if $x \not\equiv n \mod p$, then we can write $a_n = \sum_{i=0}^{p-1} f_{i,p}(n)\cdot a_i$.

For example, if I have $a_0 = 3, a_1 = 4\sqrt{3}, a_2 = \sin(2)$ and if I know the sequence $a_n$ is $3$-periodic, then I can write,

$$a_n = f_{0,3}(n) \cdot 3 + f_{1,3}(n) \cdot 4\sqrt{3} + f_{2,3}(n) \cdot \sin(2).$$

I don't know if you would consider this a "closed form" or not though.

Comment: @benguin: I would not, for only one reason: the $f_{n,p}$'s are piecewise defined. If you could express them in closed form (i.e. one piece for each $n$), then I would consider it closed form.

Comment: Here are other ways of defining a function similar to the $f_{n,p}$ one discussed earlier: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845084/is-there-a-closed-form-representation-of-this-logical-function

Comment: Perhaps one of those representations might be of interest.

Comment: "The point is to construct a single closed form expression that gives all the an's." See my first comment (or are you not interested?).

Comment: @Did Do you know if each of the $b_m$'s are able to expressed in a closed form?

Comment: @benguin Of course, since the quantities $(b_m)$ solve a linear system of size $p\times p$, depending on $(a_m)$, whose Cramer determinant is not zero. All this is standard. For example, if $\omega_p=1$, $$b_p=\frac1p(a_1+\cdots+a_p).$$ Maybe the OP could find the other parameters $b_m$ (that is, provided they are interested in the least).

Comment: @Did Gotcha, I think I understand.

Comment: Alternatively, another possibility is to use Lagrange Polynomials:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

So, using the previous example I used,
$$a_n = 3\cdot \frac{(n \mod 3) - 1}{0-1} \cdot \frac{(n \mod 3) - 2}{0-2}+4\sqrt{3}\cdot \frac{(n \mod 3) - 0}{1-0} \cdot \frac{(n \mod 3) - 2}{1-2}+\sin(2)\cdot \frac{(n \mod 3) - 0}{2-0} \cdot \frac{(n \mod 3) - 1}{2-1}$$

Comment: @benguin Not overly convinced by this type of formulas, which more or less reproduces that $a_n=a_{(n\mod 3}$ (when $p=3$). You could also use $$a_n=\sum_{m=1}^p\prod_{1\leqslant k\leqslant p, k\ne m}\frac{(n\mod p)-(k\mod p)}{(m\mod p)-(k\mod p)}a_m.$$